# How to simplify the query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query. Is there any way to simplify the query? Thanks.

```
SELECT `column1`,100*CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`) 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `column1
```

I want to calculate the percentage of each group element in the total entry. I think I duplicate this

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`)
```

Is there any way I could get the total amount of entries without using the SELECT twice?
I am using Mysql 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM()` as analytic function here to find the total counts across the entire table:

```sql
SELECT column1, 100.0*COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS pct
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY column1;
```

Here `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` finds the sum of the counts of all groups, over the entire table.  The "table," at the point when window functions get evaluated, is *after* the `GROUP BY` has already happened.  So, it is an intermediate table of all groups.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand the execution sequence of the query now.